# array Storing and and asking user to search for it

Tags: c++

The Question Is  Write a program that asks the user to enter 10 integers, stores these numbers in an array. The program should ask if 
the user would like to search an element in the array, in which case the program should then prompt the user to enter the 
number to look for. Use a recursive function find( int index, int array[] ) that does sequential search for a target in this 
array.Display an appropriate message to the user after searching the element. The program should again ask if the user 
would like to search another element in the same array and repeat this process if necessary.

i am a beginners programmer ...done this so far.   I need some help..I have tried my best to solve it

> ```
> #include<stdio.h>
> #include<conio.h>
> int main (int,int)
> {
>     int i,n;
>      int size[10];
>      printf("\nPls Enter 10 numbers for Arrays \n");
>      scanf("%d",&n);
>      for(i=0; i<10 ;i++)
>      {
>       return 0;
>
>       }      
>  getch();   
> }
> ```

Comment: In which universe does `main` have signature `(int, int)`? Change it to `int main()`.

Comment: Hi user1863982. What is the problem you have with this code? Doesn't it run? Or doesn't it do what you expect it to do? If the latter, I suggest that you step through it in a debugger to analyze its behavior.

Comment: Is this homework? If so, please mark as such.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is the code you need:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>

int n = 10,num;

void find(int index,int arr[]) {
  if(index == n) printf("Number %d not found\n");
  else if(arr[index] == num) printf("Number %d found, position %d\n.",num,index);
  else find(index + 1, arr);
}

int main() {
  int arr[n];
  printf("Please, enter 10 numbers for the array: \n");
  for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    scanf("%d",&arr[i]);
  }
  printf("Please insert the number you want to search: ");
  scanf("%d",&num);
  find(num,arr);
  system("pause"); //To pause the program before it finishes
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: ty hinafu   but if i use that code in Dev c++  ..i stores 10 arrays but after asking arrays it says type the number u wants to search,,after typing number the program disappers ..

Comment: Add ``system("pause");`` before the return, that should do the work ;)